# Probability density of rational function of a normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ be a normally distributed random variable. I would like to compute the probability density function of $Y=\frac{1+aX}{1-bX}$.

I know the quotient distribution is
$$
p(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |z|p_{A,B}(yz,z) dz
$$
where $p_{A,B}(a,b)$ is the joint distribution of of $1+aX$ and $1-bX$.

However, I am not sure how to compute the latter. I assume $A$ and $B$ cannot be taken as independent !

Comment: Start by writing out the definition of $Y$s distribution $F_Y$ as $F_Y(y) = \text{prob}(Y \leq y)$, then $F_Y(y) = \text{prob}(\frac{1 + aX}{1-bX} \leq y)$ and take it from there. You'll have to deal with the two cases $1 - bX > 0$ and $1 - bX < 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to A rural reader's comment, it was actually easier than I thought. The probability density $p(y)$ is obtained without using the quotient formula:

$$
p(y) = \frac{d}{dy}P(Y\leq y) = \frac{d}{dy}P\bigg(\frac{1+aX}{1-bX} \leq y\bigg) =  \frac{d}{dy}P\bigg(X \leq \frac{y-1}{a+by}\bigg) = \frac{d}{dy}F_{\mu,\sigma}\bigg(\frac{y-1}{a+by}\bigg) = \frac{a+b}{(a+by)^2}f_{\mu,\sigma}\bigg(\frac{y-1}{a+by}\bigg)
$$
if $1-bY\ge 0$.

Here $F_{\mu,\sigma}(z)$ is the Normal CDF and $f_{\mu,\sigma}(z)$ is the Normal PDF.